# invalid selector: The result of the xpath expression "//a[contains(@href, 'mailto')]/@href" is: [object Attr] getting the href attribute with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, getattribute

I'm currently trying to execute this command, trying to select:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href, 'mailto')]/@href").getAttribute("href")
```

To get X when `<a href="X">`.

[image]

It shows me this error:

```
invalid selector: The result of the xpath expression "//a[contains(@href, 'mailto')]/@href" is: [object Attr]. It should be an element.
```

I have tryed .getAttribute but without success. Could anyone help me with this ?

Thanks

Comment: Always add code and markup as text, and format it as code.  Images cannot easily be searched or copy-and-pasted to verify solutions.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

When you use `find_element_by_xpath`, you should supply an XPath expression that selects elements not one that selects attributes.

So drop the final `/@href`.

Answer (score 1):

This error message...

```
invalid selector: The result of the xpath expression "//a[contains(@href, 'mailto')]/@href" is: [object Attr]. It should be an element.
```

...implies that the xpath expression `"//a[contains(@href, 'mailto')]/@href"` is an invalid expression as it returns an object *attribute* where as [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) expects an [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139).

A quick solution would be to drop the *`/@href`* part from the fag end of the *xpath*.

---

### Comprehensive Solution

To print the value of the *href* attribute you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `css_selector`:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a.[href*='mailto']").get_attribute("href"))
  ```
- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[starts-with(@href, 'mailto')]").get_attribute("href"))
  ```

---

Ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "//a[starts-with(@href, 'mailto')]"))).get_attribute("value"))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='name' and @title='Download']"))).get_attribute("value"))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```